# What is the optimal scheduling strategy for K8s pods?

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling

Here is what I am working with. 
I have 3 nodepools on GKE

1. n1s1 (3.75GB)
2. n1s2 (7.5GB)
3. n1s4 (15GB)

I have pods that will require any of the following memory requests. Assume limits are very close to requests.

```
1GB, 2GB, 4GB, 6GB, 8GB, 10GB, 12GB, 14GB
```

How best can I associate a pod to a nodepool for max efficiency?

So far I have 3 strategies.

For each pod config, determine the ***“rightful nodepool”***. This is the smallest nodepool that can accommodate the pod config in an ideal world.
So for 2GB pod it's n1s1 but for 4GB pod it'd be n1s2.

1. Schedule a pod only on its *rightful nodepool.*
2. Schedule a pod only on its *rightful nodepool* or one nodepool higher than that.
3. Schedule a pod only on any nodepool where it can currently go.

Which of these or any other strategies will minimize wasting resources?

=======

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you have 3 pools like that in the first place? You generally want to use the largest instance type you can that gets you under 110 pods per node (which is the default hard cap). The job of the scheduler is to optimize the packing for you, and it's pretty good at that with the default settings.

Comment: 3 node pools are meant to handle the case where the system  only has a few 1GB or 2GB pods ..scheduling a 15GB node for those pods would be expensive. The project I am working on may have little to no workload at times.

Comment: Another case is if the system has requested 2GB pod and 14GB pod. It can be served by two 15GB nodes or a 15GB node and a 3.75GB node -- the latter being more cost effective

Comment: You know your use case better than I do, but you almost always end up being limited on packing efficiency by requests. Our nodes are all CPU request bound, and those range from 90% to 99% full depending on system load. I think you are over-optimizing this by a lot.

Comment: Having this much efficiency could lead to another problems.

1. You will end up having lot of small nodes leading to increase in cluster size.

2. During deployments, pod might get shift to another node having space and could lead small node to be empty which is also infra wastage.

3. For every new deployments or new service, your system might not be having enough space due to such optimization and will end up having long waiting time for new infra.

Comment: My personal experience is to have bit bigger node, this will avoid unnecessary overlay network issues and saves deployment time.

Comment: for now I decided to use the largest instance type node pool. Can make it more complex down the line if required.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a mix of [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) and [Node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity).

> Taints and tolerations work together to ensure that pods are not scheduled onto inappropriate nodes. One or more taints are applied to a node; this marks that the node should not accept any pods that do not tolerate the taints. Tolerations are applied to pods, and allow (but do not require) the pods to schedule onto nodes with matching taints.

You can set a taint on a node `kubectl taint nodes node1 key=value:NoSchedule`

> The taint has key `key`, value `value`, and taint effect `NoSchedule`. This means that no pod will be able to schedule onto `node1` unless it has a matching toleration.

While you are writing a `pod` yaml you can specify `PodSpec` and add toleration which will match the taint created on `node1` which will allow `pod` with either toleration to be scheduled onto `node1`

```yaml
tolerations:
- key: "key"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

or

```yaml
tolerations:
- key: "key"
  operator: "Exists"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

> Taints and tolerations are a flexible way to steer pods  *away*  from nodes or evict pods that shouldn’t be running. A few of the use cases are
>
> - **Dedicated Nodes**: If you want to dedicate a set of nodes for exclusive use by a particular set of users, you can add a taint to those nodes (say,  `kubectl taint nodes nodename dedicated=groupName:NoSchedule`) and then add a corresponding toleration to their pods (this would be done most easily by writing a custom  [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/)). The pods with the tolerations will then be allowed to use the tainted (dedicated) nodes as well as any other nodes in the cluster. If you want to dedicate the nodes to them  *and*  ensure they  *only*  use the dedicated nodes, then you should additionally add a label similar to the taint to the same set of nodes (e.g.  `dedicated=groupName`), and the admission controller should additionally add a node affinity to require that the pods can only schedule onto nodes labeled with  `dedicated=groupName`.
> - **Nodes with Special Hardware**: In a cluster where a small subset of nodes have specialized hardware (for example GPUs), it is desirable to keep pods that don’t need the specialized hardware off of those nodes, thus leaving room for later-arriving pods that do need the specialized hardware. This can be done by tainting the nodes that have the specialized hardware (e.g.  `kubectl taint nodes nodename special=true:NoSchedule`  or  `kubectl taint nodes nodename special=true:PreferNoSchedule`) and adding a corresponding toleration to pods that use the special hardware. As in the dedicated nodes use case, it is probably easiest to apply the tolerations using a custom  [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/). For example, it is recommended to use  [Extended Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#extended-resources)  to represent the special hardware, taint your special hardware nodes with the extended resource name and run the  [ExtendedResourceToleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#extendedresourcetoleration)  admission controller. Now, because the nodes are tainted, no pods without the toleration will schedule on them. But when you submit a pod that requests the extended resource, the  `ExtendedResourceToleration`  admission controller will automatically add the correct toleration to the pod and that pod will schedule on the special hardware nodes. This will make sure that these special hardware nodes are dedicated for pods requesting such hardware and you don’t have to manually add tolerations to your pods.
> - **Taint based Evictions**: A per-pod-configurable eviction behavior when there are node problems, which is described in the next section.

As for [`node affinity`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity):

> is conceptually similar to `nodeSelector` – it allows you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled on, based on labels on the node.
>
> There are currently two types of node affinity, called  `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`  and  `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`. You can think of them as “hard” and “soft” respectively, in the sense that the former specifies rules that  *must*  be met for a pod to be scheduled onto a node (just like  `nodeSelector`  but using a more expressive syntax), while the latter specifies  *preferences*  that the scheduler will try to enforce but will not guarantee. The “IgnoredDuringExecution” part of the names means that, similar to how  `nodeSelector`  works, if labels on a node change at runtime such that the affinity rules on a pod are no longer met, the pod will still continue to run on the node. In the future we plan to offer  `requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution`  which will be just like  `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`  except that it will evict pods from nodes that cease to satisfy the pods’ node affinity requirements.
>
> Thus an example of  `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`  would be “only run the pod on nodes with Intel CPUs” and an example  `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`  would be “try to run this set of pods in failure zone XYZ, but if it’s not possible, then allow some to run elsewhere”.
>
> Node affinity is specified as field  `nodeAffinity`  of field  `affinity`  in the PodSpec.
>
> ...
>
> The new node affinity syntax supports the following operators:  `In`,  `NotIn`,  `Exists`,  `DoesNotExist`,  `Gt`,  `Lt`. You can use  `NotIn`  and  `DoesNotExist`  to achieve node anti-affinity behavior, or use  [node taints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)  to repel pods from specific nodes.
>
> If you specify both  `nodeSelector`  and  `nodeAffinity`,  *both*  must be satisfied for the pod to be scheduled onto a candidate node.
>
> If you specify multiple  `nodeSelectorTerms`  associated with  `nodeAffinity`  types, then the pod can be scheduled onto a node  **only if all**  `nodeSelectorTerms`  can be satisfied.
>
> If you specify multiple  `matchExpressions`  associated with  `nodeSelectorTerms`, then the pod can be scheduled onto a node  **if one of**  the  `matchExpressions`  is satisfied.

Comment: thank you for helping! I am on GKE ..so nodeselector ->  cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool label works fine for selecting the nodepool. Toleration, taints, affinity seem more useful for cases where scheduling a pod depends on which other pods are scheduled on the node etc...